# How to optimize Rails for one kiosk user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, kiosk

I am playing around with using Rails to underpin a kiosk. This is a terminal where there is only one local user at a time.

Under this system, a browser like Chrome would access the Rails app.

Things I assume would be helpful:

- Super-fast, very lightweight Rails server (I'm using Puma).
- Eliminating standard processes/assumptions that are meant for internet website contexts (caching, CDNs, middleware, etc.).

In some level of detail preferably, how should one set up a Rails app for maximum performance in a single-user kiosk?

Comment: Are you resource-constrained on the kiosk? Do you have very low amounts of CPU or memory, or is it just a plain-old PC?

Comment: It will be somewhat resource-constrained. Probably a smallish computer like a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Hmm, I've not played with the newer Pi, but older ones really struggled (for me) with Rails 3/4 because of the low memory avaiable. If the app isn't too complex, I'd consider Sinatra as a lightweight alternative, because it pushes you towards minimalism and makes you manually include each dependency you need.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound like a non-answer, but the approach I would take is to use Rails in its default (production) configuration, and optimise performance issues as they arise in your test bed. Running Rails in production mode will likely give you more than enough performance if you have a dedicated machine for a single user (often you'll have many clients to a single Rails instance). Without testing the application, you could sink a considerable amount of time into optimisations that don't impact the user experience.

It *may* be worth sitting Rails behind Apache/nginx (Passenger is a well understood way to get a Rails app on Apache) to serve your static assets, but from the information provided so far I'd be surprised if performance optimisation was necessary at this stage.

A challenge that might be worth considering at this stage is how you'll deploy changes to your kiosk/set of kiosks. Will they be brought in for updates or need to have changes applied over-the-air? That will likely impact how you deploy it onto the machine, and in my experience is a harder thing to change later on.